# UNITY C# - how do I have 2 objects always have the same y value but the second -0.5 units

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I asked a question yesterday which was about how to have 2 objects the same y-value ALWAYS. And it worked but, I now released I need the 2nd cube the same y-value BUT with -0.5 units lower than the first one. My orginal cube is called "Player" and I have the script attachted to a cube called "TestCube". Thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class testmovement : MonoBehaviour
{  
    Transform otherTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        // you can set a reference to the "parent" cube
        otherTransform = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // here we force the position of the current object to have the same y as the parent
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, otherTransform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I now released I need the 2nd cube the same y-value BUT with -0.5 units lower than the first one"*  `otherTransform.position.y` should be `otherTransform.position.y - 0.5f`...This is really a  basic programming stuff. I suggest you start from a basic C# tutorial. This will teach you how to do arithmetic operation in C#. If you don't understand those, you'll continue to ask similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do arithmetic within the function parameter list. So by writing

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, otherTransform.position.y -0.5f, transform.position.z);
```

you can achive a constant Y offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, -0.5f, 0); //Or
transform.position = transform.position - new Vector3(0,  0.5f, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in the Inspector - use Hierarchy to set relation Parent-Children (drop one object on another) and then children Transform component IS relative to parent position so x:0, y:-0.5, z:0 will give you desired effect.